# Compare audio volume from two videos

Tags: audio, directshow, directshow.net

How Can I compare audio volume level from two videos?

One of our clients complains about our output video (from DirectShow based application) increase the audio volume between 0.5db to 1db.
How Can I check this? Is there any external tool that can help me to check audio volume signal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect your filter graph and identify if there are any filters in the audio path, which could modify the data. You can insert a filter that gets you audio stream between the audio renderer, or earler in the pipeline; then when you grab the data, you can calculate volume levels and compare to reference values.

Small discrepancies (up to 1 dB, or slightly higher) can be a result of different level calculations or downmixing, yours or taking place somewhere on the way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what really I'm looking for is an external app two compare the two videos (original and destination). I don't want touch direct show graph.

Comment: I suppose http://SuperUser.com is a better place to look for an external app/tool.